# What's the max return size of the getProgramAccounts call?

Tags: rpc, getprogramaccounts

The docs just mention "If the results of a query are too large, the response will be truncated."

What's the max data size of the query that can be returned? I understand I can do b64+zstd and fetch just pubkeys with dataSlice:0, but even with all that, what's the maximum data that I could fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum return is gated by the RPC provider. As per the cookbook documentation

> Despite its usefulness, getProgramAccounts is often misunderstood due
> to its current constraints. Many of the queries supported by
> getProgramAccounts require RPC nodes to scan large sets of data. These
> scans are both memory and resource intensive. As a result, calls that
> are too frequent or too large in scope can result in connection
> timeouts. Furthermore, at the time of this writing, the
> getProgramAccounts endpoint does not support pagination. If the
> results of a query are too large, the response will be truncated.

Comment: Possible follow up question is do the RPC providers vary this value from day to day or based on external factors like congestion? For a given RPC provider, can you assume the max size of the response will be the same from day to day?

Comment: My subjective thought would be they probably gate it with a constant. If it were me, I would want a deterministic static model for consistency. With program storage knowledge, it's probably a good idea to model discriminators in the data and use filter or memcmp.